# Comparison between theory and experiment using Mean Square Deviation

Tags: statistical-significance, model-comparison, measurement-error

I want to compare the predictions of two theories A and B to some experimental data.

The theories predict some quantity $y$ as a function of some other quantity $x$ by some analytical formula $y_A(x)$ and $y_B(x)$. Importantly, there is no fitting parameter.

I have a series of experimental data $\{X_i,Y_i\}_{i=1,\ldots,N}$ with uncertainty $\{\Delta X_i,\Delta Y_i\}_{i=1,\ldots,N}$. If there was only uncertainty on $Y$, I would (naively) compute a Mean Square Deviation $MSD$ for each theory as
$$
MSD_A = \sum_i\left(\frac{Y_i-y_A(X_i)}{\Delta Y_i}\right)^2.
$$
and similarly for theory B.

First of all, I am not sure this would be the proper thing to do in this case. Second, what is the proper way in presence of additional uncertainty on $X$? (If it simplifies the discussion, one can use the fact that in the present case, I typically have that $\Delta X/X\ll \Delta Y/Y$.)